# Is there a way to have a VM on Parallels Desktop and a VM on Virtualbox on the same host where they can communicate

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, parallels

I have Attacker VMs (Kali-via Parallels Desktop) and use Target VMs (Ubuntu via Virtualbox) and want to be able to contain my little network lab where the Targets are only accessible from the Parallels VMs and while the Attacker VMs still have access to outside the network. I have it working using the VMs on virtualbox bridged to Parallels, but was hoping for another setup maybe that was more secure. I can't seem to get the Host-Only on Virtualbox to work with the VM on Parallels.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run both Virtual Box and Parallels on the same machine.

https://forum.parallels.com/threads/virtualbox-running-in-parallel-with-parallels.297168/

> Just installed PD10 and it seems that I can run both VirtualBox
> machine and Parallels machine at the same time.
>
> Yes, Parallels Desktop 10 doesn't conflict with VirtualBox anymore and
> it is possible to run both at the same time.

Each group of machines will likely have their own subnet, so you will need to work with and experiment with connections.

The able allows you to experiment with connecting machines on different subnets but you might also try two machines in the same virtualizer, but then that is on one subnet.

Comment: everything works fine when I have both kali and target vms on virtualbox. I can deliver the payloads with no issue. However when kali is in parallels everything works as it should except metasploit. I can't get the exploit to work. I get "Exploit completed, but no session was created."

Comment: Try: https://www.cybrary.it/blog/0p3n/pivot-metasploit/  to see if that helps you across subnets.  I do think I answered your initial question.